# Edit an Edit form in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a very short and straight to the point question.

When adding an Edit form in an ADF/Swing View project (dragging a data control to the JFrame, then clicking 'Edit Form'), you get a pretty useful GUI to decide what to show and what not, and how to format the data values. However, when you finally click 'ok' there, and the form is created, there seems to be no way back into that GUI to edit the things just decided.

I want to edit forms very often and find myself deleting the forms and their bindings, then creating the entire form anew over and over again, I suppose there must be a way to edit the form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't re-enter the editor dialog. This is only possible for Tables and Trees and Tree-tables
What edits do you want to do?
You can drag and drop fields to reposition them or right click a field and select rebind and choose a different DC mapping or use properties to change behavior or "convert" to change to a different ui comp.
Exactly what edit do you want to do?

Comment: I'll try using the edit properties then, I was hoping there was a way to go back into that GUI :P. Do understand it, if generated code is edited manually, allowing for an edit GUI would probably make the program unstable. Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: the table and trees are single controls so there is an editor for them. Also their settings you can find via that "Gui" are available via the Properties.Forms are simply input text fields within panelform layout. Check out the panel form layout max rows and cols property to help control the layout. Also, docs for all components can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E24382_01/apirefs.1112/e17491/toc.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will see if I can use this to my advantage before deciding to delete a form again :P.

Facing a stone hard deadline now though, so learning any new ways is not for now..